# Should we explicitly advise people to hang around after they post a question?

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-form

On the Ask A Question page, the user is presented with a bullet pointed list. I would propose adding one more bullet point, explicitly telling users to check in on their questions. Something along these lines:

[image: Image of the sidebar on the Ask a Question Page]

> 4. Stay around for a while.
>
>    New questions tend to get the most attention. After you post, stay on the site, or check back often. Other users may ask you for more information that will help you get your answer faster!

Fairly often, especially with newer users, I see questions posted that aren't complete as written, but also aren't unrecoverable. They just need additional information that only the OP can provide. This prompts questions in the comments section, of course, as it should.

If those questions go unanswered for long enough, and "long enough" varies with the mood of the community, the question has a pretty good chance of getting closed for "Needs more detail." Unfortunately, I don't have examples handy, but I've seen potentially workable questions closed in under fifteen minutes. Generally, in the tagosphere I spend time in, half an hour or an hour is about all one can hope for before the close votes pile up, during the work day hours in North America. That timeline is longer at night (in North America) and over the weekend.

The time frame undoubtedly varies by tag, so there's no way to suggest any specifics for how often to check in, but it seems worthwhile to convey some sense of urgency to stay on top of your question for "a while". And it makes sense (to me) to phrase it in a way that seems beneficial to the user, without getting into the whole "your question's going to get closed" thing.

Now, yes, the user could come back and make the needed edits to a closed question, and then hope against hope for three reopen votes, and then hope again that somebody will come back to their reopened question and answer it. Might happen.

But it would be a better experience for all concerned if the OP would just stay handy, make the needed edits in real time, and get their answer.

Would this be any kind of a "cure all"? Of course not. But I'm not sure that users, and, again, especially new users, appreciate just how fast their question might end up in the dust heap, and adding a bullet point to the sidebar is fairly low effort and low cost.

Comment: No, they should go and find their own answer, instead waiting here aroud that someone has questions or doesn't like the question at all

Comment: I think this would help a lot, if it can get users to actually stick around. I see this quite frequently - someone posts a question which is *nearly* answerable but needs a small clarification, I (or someone else) comments about it, but after half a day OP still hasn't come back from being AFK, so the question dies. It's not a good experience for anyone involved.

Comment: @nbk, but they exhausted all possibilities for finding their own answer before they ever posted here, right? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this would help. If there's additional information needed to answer the question, someone should point it out to the OP - most likely in the comment, for which he would receive a notification (e-mail that a new item appeared in his inbox). If that doesn't make the OP go back and edit/update his question, I don't think additional bullet point would help.

Comment: @EricBrandt most posts from new users are closed and get downvotes, not as amny as here but still. So it is not helpful to stay here online and searching and finding an answer by yourself helps self-esteem

Comment: @samu, on one hand, I agree with you. On the other hand, people ask questions without reading the "How to Ask" page. That doesn't mean we don't need the "How to Ask" page. People don't check back on their questions. That doesn't mean we shouldn't tell them they should check back on their questions.

Comment: @samu "I'm not sure I understand how this would help." SO has a very short lived attention span. A question is seen a lot during the first minutes of its life and then much much less. It's important to quickly react to any comments that might come in order to use that short window of increased attention as best as possible. It's just best practice based on experience. I understand this as a possible way to tell users about it.

Comment: Already implemented - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - "After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"

Comment: There is no need for the asker to stay around. That helps them, but has no impact on us. If the question is missing information, it should be closed ***immediately***. You do not wait for them to respond before casting a close vote.

Comment: I thought that was already done - after you post you get something like "Now what: 1. wait a while. 2. Watch for feedback 3. accept an answer" or otherwise a similar list of guidelines. Might be in the question wizard but I definitely saw a mockup or screenshot of this. So, I was under the assumption it's implemented, although it's possible it was only planned or suggested.

Comment: @CodyGray In tags with lower traffic people will comment and wait for response if asked question can be salvaged. I have seen many questions that were polished in first half hour and as end result they never received down vote nor close vote. I also hope that askers learned something from experience. Another advantage is that you can save close votes for really poor or off topic questions.

Comment: @Dalija As you well know, people do a lot of things here. That doesn't mean they should or that those things are correct.

Comment: @CodyGray Even if you are coming from premise that salvageable questions should be immediately close voted and/or down voted, it definitely makes sense for OP to stick around. If you get comment pointing out what is wrong with your Q and you can fix that, doing so sooner rather than later may prevent attracting more down votes or close votes.

Comment: Hang around? No, people need to get work done too. We don't want people getting in trouble because they hang around on SO too much just because it was recommended to do so. Check back often? Heck yes.